# First Hochschild cohomology in a local selfinjective algebra

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra

Given a non-semisimple local selfinjective finite dimensional algebra $A$ with enveloping algebra $A^e$. Can one have $Ext_{A^{e}}^{1}(A,A)=0$ (that is the first hochschild cohomology zero)? I can prove that it is always nonzero in case A is addionally commutative.